# Who is the personification of Treta Yuga in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, treta-yuga

Like Shakuni is an accurate description of Dvapara Yuga and Kali Yuga is an avatar of Duryodhana and avatar Parikshit of Satya Yuga.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think Parikshit is Satya Yuga, because there does not seem to be backing for this and Parikshit does not seem to be evil (although possibly an enemy of humanity).  All the Yuga Gandharvas are probably evil, because Dvapara is evil, and if their character is based on the Yuga Dvapara should be half good half evil.

Comment: How you know Parikshit is the reincarnation of Satya Yuga?